# Report Server in Visual Studio without Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have visual Studio 2008 and sql server 2008 and Integration Services installed too. I uninstalled the reporting Services. I don't have reporting services in my machine anymore. But still I can see the Report Server project in the Visual Studio. I can still design,build and preview the reports. I am wondering, how come I can create a Report Projects without Reporting Services installed? Actually, I want to uninstalled the reporting services.

THank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects are parts of the Business Intelligence Development Studio installation that was installed during your SQL server installation (client workstation components features). So uninstalling any of the server components does not remove them and therefore you are able to still design and build these kind of projects.
As for Report Server Projects, the Report Designer component can preview the report before it gets published to the Report Server.

Regards